# HDFS set rep doesn't work

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have the following folder in HDFS: /data/2016/05/**01** and also there are many files under this folder, I tried the following commands to set the rep=2.

```
hdfs dfs -setrep -w 2 /data/2016
hdfs dfs -setrep -R 2 /data/2016
```

but when I imported files to folder /data/2016/05/**02**, the replication is still 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replication setting on the file is set when it is created and does not change when moved around. If you want to set the replication to '2', do so when it is created ( FileSystem.setReplication or set dfs.replication via configuration ) OR, run `hdfs dfs -setrep -R 2 /data/2016` after you have moved the file there.

Comment: As you said how can I set the rep=2 "when it is created", because I don't wanna set the rep each time.

Comment: That depends on what is creating the files. For example, in M/R you can set `dfs.replication` in the configuration and it will make all files created in that run have the desire replication. If you are using the java API, there is `FileSystem.setReplication`

Comment: Cool, I'm using Java API to put files, I will try FileSystem.setReplication.